# match two patterns followed one by another

Tags: regex

I'm creating a calendar where users can set events and time in single line, for example:

"6pm supper" - event with start time only

"8:00 - 16:00 work" - event with time period

Regex I'm currently using to get times:

```
[\d]{1,2}[.|:]?[\d]{0,2}[\s]?[am|pm|AM|PM]{0,2}
```

It works fine but I can't figure out how to filter out the unwanted occurrences of time if they happen, for example:

"6pm supper at '8pm' restaurant" In this example '8pm' is a restaurant name but it will be interpreted as event with time period while it's not. I suppose I have to write a regex that will only match time pattern in the beginning of line and the next pattern that follows after it without any words between but I have no success composing such a regex so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the `^` matches the begining of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you used the following regex

```
([\d]{1,2}[.|:]?[\d]{0,2}[\s]?[apm|APM]{0,2})( - )?([\d]{1,2}[.|:]?[\d]{0,2}[\s]?[apm|APM]{0,2})?(.*)
```

This would allow you to access the different sections e.g. 6pm supper at '8pm' restaurant
would be:

```
(6pm)()()( supper at '8pm' restaurant)
 $1  $2$3 $4
```

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Not sure if that can be cleaned up or but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Would `^[\d]{1,2}[.|:]?[\d]{0,2}[\s]?[am|pm|AM|PM]{0,2}` fix the problem of matching the '8pm' in your example?

The `^` is used to match the start of a line. `$` can be used for matching the end of a line (in case you need that for later;) ).

**UPDATE:**

This one's a bit ugly but it seems to work:

`[^'"][\d]{1,2}[.|:]?[\d]{0,2}[\s]?[am|pm|AM|PM]{0,2}[^'"]|^[\d]{1,2}[.|:]?[\d]{0,2}[\s]?[am|pm|AM|PM]{0,2}`

The first option ensures that if a time appears in the middle of a string, it can't be surrounded by any kind of quote character. The second option allows for times that are at the start of a string. This is ugly looking and can probably be improved somewhat... but it seems to work for me.

**UPDATE:**

I think this version's a little easier to read:

`([^'"]|^)[\d]{1,2}[.|:]?[\d]{0,2}[\s]?[am|pm|AM|PM]{0,2}[^'"]`

Comment: It will find the first occurrence of time only. I need two occurrences for events with time period.

Comment: @Anton: I'm confused: you say you want both times, but in your example, you only want the first one. Why should the second time ("8pm") be excluded in your example?

Comment: I'm sorry for not making this clear, '8pm' in last example is a name of restaurant, not an event related time. Just wanted to make it look like real world example to illustrate my problem.

Comment: @Anton: Ah those sneaky restaurateurs and their oh-so-clever names! in this example, it looks like you want to exclude a time that is surrounded by quotes. So maybe that needs to be a part of the expression.

Comment: Quotes are not the case there. If someone enters such a name without quotes this regex will fail.

Comment: @Anton: Ah so really it was a problem of finding the first Time string, and ignoring the others?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a lookbehind construct, to only select dates that are not preceded by letters other than "a","p", and "m". Something in the line of

```
(?<![letters other than apm].*)
```

According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html, not all Regex implementations support this in the needed extent, though. Most do not seem to allow .* in a lookbehind.

Comment: A good idea, but it's dependent on having a compatible regex dialect.

Comment: The idea is great but neither PHP nor Perl seem to support lookbehind with variable length and they are the only languages I can use on project. Any ideas about how this can be accomplished without lookbehind?